# Convert DateTime.Now from one UTC time zone to another

Tags: .net

Sample scenario:

I have a server in time zone +13.00 (for instance), and my users work in time zone +2.00.

How can I cause:

```
DateTime.Now
```

called on ther server to return a time that is in UTC +2.00 ? (or convert DateTime.Now result to +2.00 time zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx) method. This allows you to pass in the `DateTime` you want to convert and the source/destination time zones.

Example usage:

```
var localTime = DateTime.Now;
try
{
   Console.WriteLine("Local time: {0}", localTime);
   TimeZoneInfo destTz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
   var pacificTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, destTz);
   Console.WriteLine("Pacific time: {0}", pacificTime);
}
catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The registry does not define the Pacific Standard Time zone.");
}                           
catch (InvalidTimeZoneException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Registry data on the Pacific Standard Time zone has been corrupted.");
}
```

If you are always converting the local time zone (i.e. your not explicitly saying convert from X timezone to Y), then you can use the other [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx) overload which doesn't take the `sourceTimeZone` parameter. The time zone is worked out from the `DateTime.Kind` property of the source date (in your case, `DateTime.Now` would imply local anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary `DateTime` does not in itself contain information about time zone. (It does contain a `Kind` hinting if it's known to be a local time or universal time.)

Consider the possibility of using UTC time in the communication between server and user. Before you send, use `.ToUniversalTime()`, and after you receive, use `.ToLocalTime()`. Note that if you perform arithmetic on `DateTime` values, the `Kind` may not be conserved, and then there's the risk of accidentally performing `.ToLocalTime()` etc. more than once.

There's also the possibility to use **[`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTimeOffset.aspx)** instead. It contains the time zone together with the date and time.

```
var nowWithZone = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

You can convert to other `DateTimeOffset` with methods such as `nowWithZone.ToLocalTime()` and `nowWithZone.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(+2.0))`.

You can convert to ordinary `DateTime` with properties like `nowWithZone.LocalDateTime`, `nowWithZone.UtcDateTime`, and `nowWithZone.DateTime`.

Finally, if this is too confusing or too simple for your needs, there's the possibility to use [Noda time](http://noda-time.blogspot.dk/).